# Feasibility of extracting arbitrary locations from a given string?

Tags: perl, dictionary, awk, machine-learning, nlp

I have many spreadsheets with travel information on them amongst other things.

I need to extract start and end locations where the row describes travel, and one or two more things from the row, but what those extra fields are shouldn't be important.

There is no known list of all locations and no fixed pattern of text, all that I can look for is location names.

The field I'm searching in has 0-2 locations, sometimes locations have aliases.

#### The Problem

If we have this:

```
00229 | 445 | RTF | Jan   |  trn_rtn_co  | Chicago to Base1 
00228 | 445 | RTF | Jan   |  train       | Metroline to home coming from Base1
00228 | 445 | RTF | Jan   |  train_s     | Standard train journey to Friends
```

I, for instance (though it will vary), will want this:

```
RTF|Jan|Chicago   |Base1
RTF|Jan|Home      |Base1
RTF|Jan|NULL      |Friends
```

And then to go though, look up what `Base1` and `Friends` mean for that person (whose unique ID is RTF) and replace them with sensible locations (assuming they only have one set of 'friends'):

```
RTF|Jan|Chicago   |Rockford
RTF|Jan|Home      |Rockword
RTF|Jan|NULL      |Milwaukee
```

#### What I need

I need a way to pick out key words from the final column, such as: *Metroline to home coming from Base1*.

There are three types of words I'm looking for:

1. **Home Locations**
   These are known and limited, I can get these from a list
2. **Home Aliases**
   These are known and limited, I can get these from a list
3. **Away Locations**
   These are *unknown* but cities/towns/etc in the UK I don't know how to recognize these in the string. This is my main problem

#### My Ideas

My go to program I thought of was `awk`, but I don't know if I can reliably search to find where a proper noun (i.e. location) is used for the location names.

Is there a package, library or dictionary of standard locations?

Can I get a program to scour the spreadsheets and 'learn' the names of locations?

This seems like a problem that would have been solved already (i.e. find words in a string of text), but I'm not certain what I'm doing, and I'm only a novice programmer.

Any help on what I can do would be appreciated.

Edit:

Any answer such as "US_Locations_Cities is something you could check against", "Check for strings mentioned in a file in awk using ...", "There is a library for language X that will let a program learn to recognise location names, it's not RegEx, but it might work", or "There is a dictionary of location names *here*" would be fine.

Ultimately anything that helps me do what I want to do (i.e *get the location names*!) would be excellent.

Comment: I think you need to define your problem more clearly. Which "one or two more things" do you mean? What exactly would you expect the regex to extract from your data sample?

Comment: Sorry but as Tim said, you need to define your problem a LOT more precisely. When is a string "2 locations" - any correllation to OTHER columns? Are 2 locations always in the form of "something to somethingelse"? Any there special strings known to NOT be locations ("standard train journey?")? What other logic can be used to distinguish whether something is a location or not? Some frequency rules?

Comment: This is a very very localized problem you have that is not really generally solvable so I doubt a canned solution exists. You need to design and define a specific algorithm; and then ask on SO if you have problems implementing that algorithm.

Comment: @TimPietzcker my problem is regexing for an arbitrary location. Looking for the order (via to/from) looking up what base1 and friends mean, and returning other entries from other solumns is something I can already do and is not part of the problem, but I've tried to specify it.

Comment: @DVK This isn't homework, it's for work. It's an arbitrary string containing 0-2 locations. I don't want a coded solution (i.e someone to write the full program) but the name of a package or 'dictionary' that could be used for this sort of thing. Any Answer such as "US_Locations_Cities is somethign you could cehck against. Check for string mentioned in a file in awk using ...`<code>`" would be perfect.

Comment: @Pureferret - OK, just to be clear - are you asking if there exists some existing available database of valid geographical locations? (which is not at all related to "regexing"). In other words, are you expecting to solve your problem using only your own file as input, or using some standard dictionary file? If the latter, I would **strongly** recomment you edit the question majorly to clarify that.

Comment: Regexing was the closest term I could think of for what I wanted to do. I'll edit my question appropriately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry to tell you, but i think this is not 100% programmable.
The best bet would be to define some standard searches:

- Chicago to Base1
  [WORD] to [WORD]:
  where "to" is fixed and you look for exactly one word before and after. the word before then is your source and word after your target
- Metroline to home coming from Base1
  [WORD] to [WORD] coming from [WORD]:
  where "to" and "coming from" is fixed and you look for three words in the appropriate slots.
- etc

if you can match a source and target -> ok
if you cannot match something then throw an error for that line and let the user decide or even better implement an appropiate correction and let the program automatically reevaluate that line.

these are non-trivial goals.
consider:

- Cities out of us of a
- Non english text entries
- Abbreviations

for automatic error corrections try to match the found [WORD]'s with a list of us or other cities.
if the city is not found throw an error. if you find that error either include that not found city to your city list or translate a city name in a publicly known (official) name.

Answer (score 1):

The best I can suggest is that, as long as your locations are all US cities, you can use a database of zip codes such as [this one](http://www.zip-codes.com/).

I don't know how you expect any program to pick up things like `Friends` or `Base1`

Comment: Things like Friends and Base1 should be a short enough list to match against.

Comment: Then if you're happy with dealing with those you should remove the issue from your question

Comment: I did, but then people complain I wasn't being specific enough.

Answer (score 1):

I have to agree with hacktick that *as it stands now*, it is not programmable. It seems that the only solution is to invent a language or protocol.

I think an easy implementation follows:

1. In this language you have two keywords: `to` and `from` (you could also possibly allocate `at` as a keyword synoym for `from` as well).
2. These keywords define a portion of string that follows as a "scan area" for 
   recognizing names

I'm only planning on implementing the simplest scan, but as indicated at the end of the post allows you to do your fallback.

1. In the implementation you have a "Preferred Name" hash, where you define the names that you want displayed for things that appear there.

   ```
   { Base1   => 'Rockford'
   , Friends => 'Milwaukee'
   , ...
   }
   ```
2. You could `split` your sentences by chunks of text between the keywords, using the following rules:

   A. First chunk, if not a keyword is taken as the value of 'from'.
   A. On this or any subsequent chunk, if keyword then save the next chunk
      after *that* for that value.
   A. Each value is "scanned" for a preferred phrase before being stored
      as the value.

   ```
   my @chunks 
       = grep {; defined and ( s/^\s+//, s/\s+$//, length ) } 
         split /\b(from|to)\s+/i, $note
       ;
   my %parts = ( to => '', from => '' );
   my $key;
   do { 
       last unless my $chunk = shift @chunks;
       if ( $key ) { 
           $parts{ $key } = $preferred_title{ $chunk } // $chunk;
           $key = '';
       }
       elsif ( exists $parts{ lc $chunk } ) { 
           $key = lc $chunk;
       }
       elsif ( !$parts{from} ) { 
           $parts{from} = $preferred_title{ $chunk } // $chunk;
       }
   } while ( @chunks );
   say join( '|', $note, @parts{ qw<from to> } );
   ```

At the very least, collecting these values and printing them out can give you a sieve to decide on further courses of action. This will tell you that `'home coming`' is perceived as a 'from' statement, as well as `'Standard train journey'`.

You *could fix the `'home coming'` by amending the regex thusly:

```
 /\b(?:(?:coming )?(from)|(to))\s+/i
```

And we could add the following key-value pair to our preferred_title hash:

```
home => 'Home'
```

We could simply define `'Standard train journey' => ''`, or we could create a list of rejection patterns, where we reject a string as a meaningful value if they fit a pattern.

But they allow you to dump out a list of values and refine your scan of data. Another idea is that as it seems that your pretty consistent with your use of capitals (except for 'home') for places. So we could increase our odds of finding the right string by matching the chunk with

```
/\b(home|\p{Upper}.*)/
```

Note that this still considers `'Standard train journey'` a proper location. So this would still need to be handled by rejection rules.

Here I reiterate that this can be a minimal approach to scanning the data to the point that you can make sense of what it this system takes to be locations and "80/20" it down: that is, hopefully those rules handle 80 percent of the cases, and you can tune the algorithm to handle 80 percent of the remaining 20, and iterate to the point that you simply have to change a handful of entries at worst.

Then, you have a specification that you would need to follow in creating travel notes from then on. You could even scan the notes as they were entered and alert something like
'No destination found in note!'.